# 7za - Extract file with password

Tags: 7z

I have a `.7z` file which I need to extract the contents of. The problem is, that it's password protected and currently, I have to SSH into the server and enter the password. I would like to this without the need of this.

Is this possible?

I have tried:

```
7za x file.7z -ppassword pass
```

But does not work, just returns "No files to process"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a year+ late, but in case anyone else googles this, use:

`7za x file.7z -p'your_password'`

Wrapping the password in single quotes does the trick

Comment: Single quote doesn't work on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the command should be

```
7za x file.7z -pyour_password
```

Whereas "-ppassword pass" uses password "password" and tries to extract "pass" file from your archive.

Comment: No, just returns "Wrong password" Sub items error 1 - Is the right password, however